# SCILAB undefined vairable error when using 'polarplot'

Tags: plot, scilab

I am getting the following error while running polarplot in scilab

```
// Program to plot using polarplot function
t= 0:.01:2*%pi;
polarplot(sin(t))
xtitle('Using polarplot'
```

result:

```
exec('D:\mangesh\SCILAB PROJ\sample\polarplot.sce', -1)
at line    13 of function polarplot ( C:\PROGRA~1\SCILAB~1.1\modules\graphics\macros\polarplot.sci line 25 )
at line 3 of executed file D:\mangesh\SCILAB PROJ\sample\polarplot.sce

Undefined variable: rho
```

Answer (score 1):

The polarplot function requires at least 2 input arguments theta and rho,
In your example you forgot to give the evolution of the radius. for example:

```
   polarplot(sin(t), ones(t))
```

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by the other user as well the `polarplot` function requires at least two input vectors, like most of other plotting functions. It this case you probably want something like:

```
// Program to plot using polarplot function
t = 0:.01:2*%pi;
polarplot(t, sin(t));
xtitle('Using polarplot');
```

which yields:

> [image]

Comment: @mangesh no problem. Happy to give back to the community.  Please accept the correct answers and give them some thumbs up :) and if they are not what you were looking for communicate and explain your issue further.